# Unable to login to Google service with Selenium in Java: “This browser or app may not be secure.”

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium

I have this problem with selenium, i try to run my code below but i have this error: https://i.postimg.cc/VNd3F4rm/u2zrn.jpg .

Image of my "Signing in to Google": https://i.stack.imgur.com/w3POX.png (As you can see "App password" does not appear to me)

**I have already tried to disable the "less secure apps" section in account settings and checked if JavaScipt was actived, but without success.**

```java
 WebDriver driver= new ChromeDriver();
         driver.navigate().to("https://accounts.google.com/signin");

driver.findElement(By.name("identifier")).sendKeys("email@gmail.com");
         driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/button")).click();

driver.findElement(By.name("password")).sendKeys("*******");
```

Comment: Have you made any progress?

Comment: No, nothing to do. When I activeted "2-Step Verification", Google doesn't let me disable the section "less secure app". Even if I set an app passoword, Google notes that I'm using a Selenium bot

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to go to your Google Account settings and under Security, you need to register your test app with a password. I had to do this in order to implement in Cucumber a way to send and read emails.

[image]

Then, from your test application, you will use those credentials (not your real Google creds) to authenticate and do what you need. You could also try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57602974/gmail-is-blocking-login-via-automation-selenium).

Comment: There isn't the section "App password". It could be an old image?

Comment: Unless Google changed it less than 2 hours ago, the image is recent. I literally took it seconds before I posted it.

Comment: I really don'y know if this section is aviable in every country and if that's actually the reason why this doesn't appear to me. I can see only 3 section: The first one is "Password" (as your), the second one is "Use your phone to sign in" and the third one is "2-Step Verification". I allegate you the picture in my question box.

Comment: I activeted "2-Step Verification" and now I can see the "App password" section

Answer (score 0):

I have another solution in python that might help you.
Use [Seleniumwire](https://pypi.org/project/selenium-wire/) with [undetected browser v2](https://pypi.org/project/selenium-wire/#bot-detection)

> Note: put chromedriver in your sys path.

```
from seleniumwire.undetected_chromedriver.v2 import Chrome, ChromeOptions
import time

options = {}
chrome_options = ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument('--user-data-dir=hash')
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
chrome_options.add_argument("--incognito")
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")
# chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
browser = Chrome(seleniumwire_options=options, options=chrome_options)

browser.get('https://gmail.com')
browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="identifierId"]').send_keys('your-email')
browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="identifierNext"]/div/button').click()
time.sleep(5)
browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="password"]/div[1]/div/div[1]/input').send_keys('you-password')
browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="passwordNext"]/div/button').click()
```

In addition to this, selenium wire has many awesome features, check out Github [repository](https://github.com/wkeeling/selenium-wire)