# Trying to sign into google using a selenium python script

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver

I am using selenium to open and sign into google accounts as my first step. I have successfully opened and filled the email response although upon submitting I receive the error of

> "This browser or app may not be secure. Learn more Try using a
> different browser. If you’re already using a supported browser, you
> can refresh your screen and try again to sign in." From google.

Is there any way to get around this? Here is my code below.

---

```
from selenium import webdriver

from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

import time

PATH = "C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)

driver.get("https://accounts.google.com/")
print(driver.title)

search = driver.find_element_by_name("identifier")

search.send_keys("email goes here")

search.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
```

Comment: You can once refer this [gmail](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57602974/16452840)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [“This browser or app may not be secure” error while attempting to login in to Gmail account using GeckoDriver Firefox through Selenium and Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59515561/this-browser-or-app-may-not-be-secure-error-while-attempting-to-login-in-to-gm)

Answer (score 0):

Was having the same issue and i found [this](https://gist.github.com/ikegami-yukino/51b247080976cb41fe93) thread in GitHub.

The solution that worked for me was to use this driver: `undetected_chromedriver` instead of the normal `ChromeDriver`.

```
    import undetected_chromedriver.v2 as uc

    chrome_options = uc.ChromeOptions()
    chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
    chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-popup-blocking")
    chrome_options.add_argument("--profile-directory=Default")
    chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-plugins-discovery")
    chrome_options.add_argument("--incognito")
    chrome_options.add_argument("user_agent=DN")

    self.browser = uc.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
    self.browser.delete_all_cookies()

    # example of loggin in to youtube without getting that issue
    self.browser.get('http://youtube.com')

    login_button_init = self.browser.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@aria-label='Sign in']") 
    login_button_init.click()

    # locate the login button
    login_button = self.browser.find_element_by_xpath("//paper-button[@aria-label='Sign in']")
    login_button.click()

    # get email and set to email input box
    email = self.browser.find_element_by_id("identifierId")
    myemail = os.environ.get('YOUTUBE_EMAIL')
    email.send_keys(myemail)

    # click next button
    email_next_button = self.browser.find_element_by_id("identifierNext")
    email_next_button.click()

    # get password and set to password input box
    password = self.browser.find_element_by_name("password")
    mypassword = os.environ.get('YOUTUBE_PASSWORD')
    password.send_keys(mypassword)
    sleep(2)

    # click next button to log in
    pass_next_button = self.browser.find_element_by_id("passwordNext")
    pass_next_button.click()
```