# Google chrome login problem after running selenium script

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

So when we run the python script below we get the error in the picture when trying to log into google with selenium.

Here is the code and the pic is the error message. It just does not like it for some reason. We have added time sleep and that is all we came up with. We get the same error running Firefox. Any help would be appreciated.

[image]

```
 # Open Gmail login page
    
    driver = uc.Chrome(use_subprocess=True,service = service)
    driver.get("https://accounts.google.com/signin")

    # Enter email and click Next
    email_field = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="identifierId"]')))
    email_field.send_keys(email+str('\n'))
    #next_button = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="identifierNext"]/div/button')))
    #next_button.click()

    # Enter password and click Submit
    password_field = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.NAME, 'Passwd')))
    password_field.send_keys(password+str('\n'))
    #submit_button = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="passwordNext"]/div/button')))
    #submit_button.click()

    time.sleep(3)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57602974/gmail-is-blocking-login-via-automation-selenium - Check this, if it helps.

Comment: I looked at that twice and got nothing

Comment: You can go throw this thread [Gmail is blocking login via automation selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57602974/gmail-is-blocking-login-via-automation-selenium)

Comment: tried them all same infor

Comment: ANyone know? Please help!

Comment: it means that the site detects the use of automation software, a workaround is to use cookies or an already logged in user profile, in this way you can skip the login procedure