# How to automate Gmail Account Using Robot Framework

Tags: authentication, selenium-webdriver, gmail, robotframework

I am a beginner in Robot Framework. I am trying to automate Gmail Account but it seems that Google is blocking me. I am just able to put in the email and as soon I click on the Next Button a message is being displayed which means that I am blocked from accessing it. So please let me know how can we do this.[Message Shown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o8CTT.png)

I used ImapLibrary as well but was not able to login.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [GMail is blocking login via Automation (Selenium)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57602974/gmail-is-blocking-login-via-automation-selenium)

Answer (score 0):

With some commercial websites, they can detect that a machine or a real person connects to their sites. And with machines, it's blocked because they don't want the noise data. You can try other websites that are built for automation testing (like below):
(In about 10-20 minutes, the data will be cleared, so you don't need to worry about your data spams these webs)

1. NopCommerce: https://demo.nopcommerce.com/
2. LiveTechpada: http://live.techpanda.org/
3. Demo Guru: Login Site: https://demo.guru99.com/ and Register Site: https://demo.guru99.com/v4/